# Unable to trigger onChange when data is changed from MutableLiveData

Tags: android, android-livedata

I have a `MovieRepository` which retrieves a JSON using Retrofit, it is responsible for all the data used in this app, the single source of truth. Then, I have a `MainActivityViewModel` which uses the `MovieRepository`, it is responsible to supply data to the UI layer.

Inside of my `MainActivity` I have a menu option: `Most popular` and `Top rated option`, when the user taps on it, I would like to change to UI. Here is my approach:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.top_rated_menu:
            viewModel.getMovie(MovieAPIUtils.Endpoints.TOP_RATED_ENDPOINT);
            return true;

        case R.id.most_popular_menu:
            viewModel.getMovie(MovieAPIUtils.Endpoints.POPULAR_ENDPOINT);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

My `getMovie()` method in the View Model is this:

```
public class MainActivityMovieViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivityMovieViewModel.class.getSimpleName();

    private MutableLiveData<ReturnMovie> movie;
    private MovieRepository repo = new MovieRepository();
    private String search = null;

    public LiveData<ReturnMovie> getMovie(String searchTerm) {

       if (movie == null) {
           movie = repo.search(searchTerm);
       }
        return movie;
    }
}
```

And here is my repository:

```
public class MovieRepository {

    private static final String TAG = MovieRepository.class.getSimpleName();

    public MutableLiveData<ReturnMovie> search(final String term) {
        final MutableLiveData<ReturnMovie> data = new MutableLiveData<>();

        MovieService service = ServiceGenerator.createService(MovieService.class);
        Call<ReturnMovie> call = service.requestMovie(term, MovieAPIUtils.KEY);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ReturnMovie>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ReturnMovie> call, Response<ReturnMovie> response) {
                ReturnMovie movie = response.body();
                data.setValue(movie);
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ReturnMovie> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, t.toString());
            }
        });
        return data;
    }
}
```

For some reason, when `viewModel.getMovie()` is called, the `onChange` method from the `LiveData` is not triggered, I tried reading the documentation on Android Architecture and tried different approach, but still failed.

Here is my `OnCreate()` in MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainActivityMovieViewModel.class);
    initRecyclerViewWithMovies();

    final Observer<ReturnMovie> observer = new Observer<ReturnMovie>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable ReturnMovie returnMovie) {
            mMovieAdapter.swapCursor(returnMovie.getResults());
        }
    };

    viewModel.getMovie(MovieAPIUtils.Endpoints.POPULAR_ENDPOINT)
            .observe(this, observer);
}
```

For the full code:

https://github.com/brendoncheung/PopularMovie/tree/mvvm_approach

Thanks so much!